# Open link generated in Jupyter notebook into new browser tab

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am setting up an API script and I am using Jupyter Lab on a virtual machine. When I run the cell with the login code, I get the following error.

> WARNING: We could not open a usable web browser for authentication purposes, or alternatively, please copy the below link:

I then have to manually copy the link into a new browser tab and the API will work. My question is around automating this, is there any way I can have my script copy the link from the Jupyter notebook output cell and then automatically copy it into a new browser tab?